# How can I configure my server to send email, PHP installed on IIS Windows Server 2008

Tags: php, windows, email

I am trying to use the MAIL() function in  PHP to send emails notifications.

So here is my how I am using it.

```
$to      = 'email@address.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

this what I get

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

but it does not send. I am not sure if my server is currectly configured correctly so the mail function works. I am running PHP 5.3.19 on Windows Server 2008 R2

My question is how can I make sure the the server is configured correctly to send emails?
How can I trace the message to I can see why it did not do to the targeted personal?

Thanks

Comment: either run a local mail-server or connect to a remote one like Gmail or your isp

Answer (score 0):

When working on Windows, PHP has to be configured to send email through an SMTP server. By default, localhost is used. See the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp) on how to change the php.ini settings to change your SMTP information.

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
```

I believe you can [install IIS7 SMTP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), but I've never used that myself, so I could be wrong (I've used Exchange or linux boxes for my SMTP needs). Whatever you do, make sure you configure it to ensure it's not an open relay and/or firewall it to only localhost.

Edit: [This article](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7-and-above) on iis.net may help.

Comment: I have installed SMTP on the server. And in the php.ini file i have SMTP set to localhost and smtp_port set to 25.  I now get this error Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for email@address.com

Comment: So I followed some instruction on the web and I got rid of the warnings but the messages are not being delivered. I send a test but it do receive it and I get no errors/warning.  What do I do?

Comment: Do you have a static IP address? Many services decline emails sent from a dynamic IP address.

Comment: Yes in fact, my server is on a network along with other servers. I also have an exchange server which we use to send/receive emails via web mail and Microsoft outlook. I am not sure if this have anything to do with this issue. Thanks

Comment: If you have an exchange server, you might can just change your send connector to accept anonymous mail from that server and use one of those IPs instead of local host.

Comment: I have done that but it is not working as well. I am not sure if there are a permission issue but I am not sure where to start. If it is possible to use SMTP on my local host at the same time I have an exchange server that will be better as it will take a load off of my exchange servers.

Comment: Hmm! Maybe this will help, wish I had found it sooner for ya! http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7-and-above It is a little involved, but hey... this is PHP on IIS.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am getting closer and closer. Now my server is sending emails only to internal domains and not external domains. So if I send an email to myname@mydomain.com I recive it no problem but I I send to myname@gmail.com I don't! Any help on that?  Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have anything in the error logs? It may also be helpful to try relaying through telnet to see what the third party mail server is replying. Figuring out mail delivery issues can sometimes be a pain.